# C++ how to access a method from object without having circular dependencies?

Tags: c++, reference, circular-dependency

**What I have:**

A class Game that contains:

- A reference to a class OpenGLManagement
- A std:vector of Pieces

A class Piece that contains:

- A method to rotate() the Piece

A class OpenGLManagement that contains:

- A method doStuff()

Something like this (I just left the code useful to ask the question):

```
class Piece
{
public:
   void rotate(); //rotate this piece
}

class OpenGLManagement 
{
public:
   doStuff(); //How can I access the rotate() function on the Piece class?
}

class Game
{
public:
   Game(OpenGLManagement& openGLObj) : m_openGL(openGLObj) {}
private:
   OpenGLManagement& m_openGL; //a reference to my object
   std::vector<Piece> m_pieces; //my vector of pieces
}

int main()
{
    OpenGLManagement myOpenGL;
    Game myGame(myOpenGL);

    //...etc

    return 0;
}
```

**My objective:**

**How can I access the rotate() function on the Piece class from the doStuff() function?**

What can/should I change on my code to accomplish that in a good C++ practice?:)

I wanted to avoid circular dependencies by having references pointing to everywhere. And besides, I need to create the myOpenGL object first...so I don't know yet the reference to the Game object...

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you have an inversion here, where `OpenGLManagement` should serve as a controller for `Game` and not the other way around, or the `doStuff()` method needs to take `Game&` as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a class that instantiates the other two with static objects.
Then I created two get methods for references.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the `Piece` class above the others.

Comment: The above code was just to illustrate my problem as I said above.

Comment: @waas1919: And? If this answer doesn't solve the problem, then the question was unclear. What are you actually having trouble with? Which `Piece` do you want `doStuff` to rotate?

Comment: I want the doStuff() to rotate one of the pieces on my vector... but I don't know how to access the vector of pieces..

Comment: @waas1919: I can think of several ways to do this, but I have no idea which, if any, would satisfy you. Your architecture is so weird that I cannot make confident guesses about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you properly organize includes, there will be no circular dependencies. You do not need `OpenGlManagment` class for definition of `Piece` and don't need 'Piece' for `OpenGlManagment` class definition. At least i suppose so from your code. If you put function definitions in *.cpp files and only class definitions and forward declarations in proper *.h files everything should be fine. Like this:

Piece.h

```
class Piece
{
public:
   void rotate(); //rotate this piece
}
```

Piece.cpp

```
#include "Piece.h"

void Piece::rotate(){
//definition here
}
```

OpenGlManagment.h

```
class Piece;

class OpenGLManagement 
{
public:
   void doStuff();
}
```

OpenGlManagment.cpp

```
#include "OpenGlManagment.h"
#include "Piece.h"

void OpenGLManagement::doStuff(){
//use your Piece methods here
}
```